# SagemakerEndpoint model doesn't return full output, only when prompted with langchain

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, langchain, large-language-model, vector-database

I have a huggingface model deployed behind a sagemaker endpoint which produces outputs as expected when run prediction against it directly. However, when I initialize it with SagemakerEndpoint class from langchain, it only return two characters and sometimes an empty string. I scoured through the internet and langchain docs for the last couple days and my initialization and chain prompting aspects of the code seem to be in line with the docs guidelines and anecdotal recommendations laid out.
I think this either a lack integration support for huggingface models deployed with sagemaker or I'm missing something here that's not been written in the docs and examples. Please review and let me know either way.

Relevant code block that will reproduce behavior:

```
endpoint = "xxxxxx-2023-07-14-05-34-901"

parameters = {
    "do_sample": True,
    "top_p": 0.95,
    "temperature": 0.1,
    "max_new_tokens": 256,
    "num_return_sequences": 4,
}
    
class ContentHandler(LLMContentHandler):
        content_type = "application/json"
        accepts = "application/json"
        
        def transform_input(self, prompt: str, model_kwargs: Dict) -> bytes:
            input_str = json.dumps({"inputs": prompt, **model_kwargs})
            return input_str.encode('utf-8')
        
        def transform_output(self, output: bytes) -> str:
            response_json = json.loads(output.read().decode("utf-8"))
            return response_json[0]['generated_text']
        
content_handler = ContentHandler()
        
sm_llm=SagemakerEndpoint(
        endpoint_name=endpoint,
#        credentials_profile_name="credentials-profile-name",
        region_name="us-west-2",
        model_kwargs= parameters,
        content_handler=content_handler,
    )

print("sm_llm: ", sm_llm)

vectordb = Chroma(persist_directory="db", embedding_function=embedding, collection_name="docs")
retriever = vectordb.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'k':3})
print("retriever: ", retriever)

qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=sm_llm, 
                                  chain_type="stuff", 
                                  retriever=retriever,
                                  return_source_documents=True)
```

Prompting:

```
system_prompt = """<|SYSTEM|># Your are a helpful and harmless assistant for providing clear and succint answers to questions."""

question = "What is your purpose?"
query = (system_prompt + "<|USER|>" + question + "<|ASSISTANT|>")
llm_response = qa_chain(query)
print(llm_response['result'])

----------------------------------------------------------------

Output:
Use the following pieces of context to answer the question at the end. If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer.

<some doc context from vectordb goes here - removed due to info sensitivity>

Question: # Your are a helpful and harmless assistant for providing clear and succint answers to questions.
What is your purpose?
Helpful Answer:
```

As shown, model doesn't return any output, for 'Helpful Answer:', in this setting when prompted with RetrievalQA from langchain. This is not the case when I prompt the model directly with 'predictor.predict()' function.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. When using the HuggingFaceEndpoint everything worked just fine, but when I changed to the SagemakerEndpoint I was getting the answers truncated.
I was able to debug the code and find out that the model kwargs were not being passed properly, so my `transform_input` looks like this:

```
def transform_input(self, prompt: str) -> bytes:
        request = {'inputs': prompt,
                    "parameters": { "do_sample": True,
                                "top_p": 0.9,
                                "temperature": 0.85,
                                "max_new_tokens": 1024,
                                "stop": ["<|endoftext|>", "</s>"],
                                "early_stopping": True}}

        input_str = json.dumps(request)
        print(input_str)
        return input_str.encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue. When using Sagemaker Endpoint directly, the complete response is returned.
Also, when trying with langchain.HuggingFaceHub, it's returing the complete response. With LLMContentHandler, it's returning a truncated response.

```
from langchain import PromptTemplate, LLMChain
ENDPOINT_NAME = "open-chat-falcon-7B-24-07-2023-05-44-26"

from typing import Dict

from langchain import PromptTemplate, SagemakerEndpoint
from langchain.llms.sagemaker_endpoint import LLMContentHandler
import json]

parameters = {
"early_stopping": True,
"length_penalty": 2.0,
"max_new_tokens": 1024,
"temperature": 0.01,
}

class ContentHandler(LLMContentHandler):
content_type = "application/json"
accepts = "application/json"

def transform_input(self, prompt: str, model_kwargs: Dict) -> bytes:
    input_str = json.dumps({"inputs": prompt, **model_kwargs})
    return input_str.encode("utf-8")

def transform_output(self, output: bytes) -> str:
    response_json = json.loads(output.read().decode("utf-8"))
    return response_json[0]["generated_text"]
content_handler = ContentHandler()

llm=SagemakerEndpoint(
endpoint_name=ENDPOINT_NAME,
region_name="us-west-2",
model_kwargs=parameters,
content_handler=content_handler,
)

template = """
You are an artificial intelligence assistant. The assistant gives helpful, detailed, and polite answers to the user's questions.

{question}
"""
prompt = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=["question"])
llm_chain = LLMChain(prompt=prompt, llm=llm)

question = "Write a resignation letter addressing the manager"

print(llm_chain.run(question))
```

OUTPUT:
You are an artificial intelligence assistant. The assistant gives helpful, detailed, and polite answers to the user's questions.

Write a resignation letter addressing the manager
Dear [Manager],

I am writing to inform you of my intention to resign from my

```
llm.predict(question)
```

OUTPUT:
Write a resignation letter addressing the manager\nDear [Manager],\n\nI am writing to inform you of my intention to resign from

```
import boto3
import json
import time

runtime= boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')

payload = """Write a resignation letter addressing the manager"""

parameters = {
"early_stopping": True,
"length_penalty": 2.0,
"max_new_tokens": 1024,
"temperature": 0.01,
}

start = time.time()
response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
ContentType='application/json',
Body=json.dumps({
"inputs": payload,
"parameters": parameters
})
)
time_taken = (time.time() - start)
output = json.loads(response['Body'].read())

print("Time Taken (s): ", time_taken)
print(output[0]['generated_text'])
```

OUTPUT:
Write a resignation letter addressing the manager
Dear [Manager],

I am writing to inform you of my intention to resign from my current position at [Company Name]. My last day of work will be [insert date].

I have appreciated my time here and the opportunities given to me. I have learned a lot and grown professionally during my time with the company.

I am confident that I will be able to find a suitable position in the future. If you need any assistance during this transition, please do not hesitate to contact me.

Thank you for the opportunity and I look forward to hearing from you.

Sincerely,
[Your Name]